# Video Uploading in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

```
$valid_formats = array("mp4");
$max_file_size = ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');  //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;
echo $_FILES['files']['size'];
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
echo "hello";
print_r($_FILES['files']['name']);}
```

The above written line executes good while uploading other stuffs like image and pdf.But it fails while uploading the video and shows null array

Comment: Probably because the file is to large. What is `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` set to in your `php.ini`? And how big is the video file you'r trying to upload?

Comment: Dump the whole files arrsy

Comment: You cannot set the `upload_max_filesize` using `ini_set()` and `100M` does **not** mean `100kb` =)

Answer (score 0):

I think this probably has to do with that the file you are trying to upload is to large. Try to increase the allowed upload file size by changing the following values in your [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) and then restart your webserver:

```
post_max_size = 16M;
upload_max_filesize = 16M;
```

I would also enable [`error_reporing`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to try to find what's going on. You can turn it on and display errors on the page, by adding the following to the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You can also try to track down the problem by looking in your log files, for instance the apache log file under:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```